# PHP CRUD - Update function

Tags: php

I am creating the `BindableCollection` class which implements `IBindableCollection`.

What I want to do is CRUD operations above the collection (array of associative arrays). I have all of the CRUD functionallity, but I lack update function which doesn't work.

#### Code

```
public function updateFirstWhere($attr, $value, $updateCallback) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach($this->value as $data) {
        if($data[$attr] == $value) {
            call_user_func_array($updateCallback, $this->value[$i]);
            return;
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

When I pass the `$this->value[$i]` (which is all of the data inside collection) to the callback function and I do something like that:

```
public function deleteThePerson($sender) {
    $this->collection->updateFirstWhere("id", $sender->data_id, function(&$data) {
        $data["name"] = "durisvk";
    });
}
```

I don't see the change in the data.

I want to set the `name` to `durisvk` but I can't. 
Any Ideas Please?

Comment: I think you have a few issues here, but first being that `call_user_func_array` calls the callback function passing each value in the array as it's own argument. So if you have for example `id`, `name`, `whatever` as values in your `$this->value[$i]` array, each of those is passed as a separate argument to your callback. So `$data` is whatever the first value in `$this->value[$i]`, not the array. In your callback do a `print_r(func_get_args());` to see everything that was passed in.

Comment: Second there might be an issue with `call_user_func_array` and passing by reference in that the array you pass in has to be references to other variables. You can see this in the manual under the references example for [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/call_user_func_array). This can likely be solved by just looping over `$this->value[$i]` and making a reference to each value as a reference in a temporary array. Both of these issues should write to your error log so you should also check that.

Comment: can you please show me how to loop over the array and get the references? should I use foreach or for?

Comment: `$tmp = []; foreach($this->values[$i] as $k=>$v)$tmp[$k] = &$this->values[$i][$k];` After that, you can pass in `$tmp`. Not sure if this will fix it, but it might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        // UPDATE CRUD element.
        $idc = -1;
        $naam = "";
        $merk = "";
        $typ = "";
        $kl = "";

        $con = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cars_database", "root", "");
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        if(isset($_GET["action"])) {
            if($_GET["action"] == "edit") {
                if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
                    $statement = $con->prepare("UPDATE cars_assigment SET Name=?, Brand=?, Type=?, Color=? WHERE Id = ?");

                        $statement->bindValue(1, $_POST["Name"]);
                        $statement->bindValue(2, $_POST["Brand"]);
                        $statement->bindValue(3, $_POST["Type"]);
                        $statement->bindValue(4, $_POST["Color"]);
                        $statement->bindValue(5, $_POST["Id"]);

                        $statement->execute();
                }


                $statement = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM cars_assigment WHERE Id = ?");
                $statement->bindValue(1, $_GET["Id"]);  
                $statement->execute();

                $record = $statement->fetchObject();
                if($record != false) {
                    $idc =      $record-> Id;
                    $naam =     $record-> Name;
                    $merk =     $record-> Brand;
                    $typ =  $record-> Type;
                    $kl  =$record-> Color;
                }
            }
        }

    ?>


    <h1> Update </h1> 

        <form method="POST">
        ID:         <input type="text" name="Id" value="<?php echo $idc ?>"> 
        Naam:       <input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo $naam ?>"> 
        Brand:      <input type="text" name="Brand" value="<?php echo $merk ?>"> 
        Type:   <input type="text" name="Type" value="<?php echo $typ ?>"> 
        Color:  <input type="text" name="Color" value="<?php echo $kl ?>">
        <input name="Id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $idc; ?>"> </input> 
        <input type="submit"  value="Save"> </input>
        </form>



</body>
```

Comment: @bjansen, Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer and, please, read this guide on [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Just a code dump - is not a "good answer".